# How to login a PC from remote terminal (SSH)?

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there any way to login a PC from CLI as if I would log in manually on the PC?

I have root access through ssh, but I need to log in the PC for certain programs to start.

I don't want to enable auto login. Does anyone have an idea?

I'm using Linux Mint 20 Ulyana.

Comment: You can start programs, but they may terminate when you log out, unless you use `nohup`. Another option may be to let the system's `init` system take care of this, which it already does for web servers and other services. Either way, your question isn't really about programming and would probably better fit on [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

If you have the root access and the os is hosted on a server then  u can use Google chrome remote desktop.

URL: https://remotedesktop.google.com/support/

Set up via SSH: https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless